# how to reference a schema variable in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to learn plpgsql code to automate some data cleaning in a database.

My current task is to replace all of '999' values in numeric fields with 'NaN'. What I am trying to do is: 
1) find all columns in a schema that are numeric
2) loop through these and use 'update/replace'

My code is below. I think my main problem is finding out how to reference the schema.table in the update statement (but I am sure there are other things I have not done too well).

The error that I am getting is that the relation is not recognised.
Any assistance would be appreciated

Becky

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION household.nodata_replace(schemanm text)
RETURNS VOID as $$
DECLARE
  cname text;
  tname text;
BEGIN
   --FOR col IN
  for cname,tname in SELECT column_name::text,table_name::text FROM information_schema.columns
     where table_schema = schemanm and data_type in ('integer','double precision')

     LOOP

     RAISE NOTICE 'cname is: % from %', cname, tname;
     EXECUTE 'update '||schemanm::regclass||'.' ||tname::regclass||
 ' set ' || quote_ident(cname) ||' = replace('  || quote_ident(cname) ||', 999, NaN);';
     END LOOP;


END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2):

try to rework your query like following:

```
EXECUTE 'update '|| (schemanm||'.'||tname)::regclass ||' set ' || quote_ident(cname) ||' = ''NaN'' WHERE '|| quote_ident(cname) ||' = 999;'
```

because casting to `regclass` is trying to search within registered relations. and schema is not relation.

or you can

```
EXECUTE 'update '|| quote_ident(schemanm)||'.'||quote_ident(tname) ||' set ' || quote_ident(cname) ||' = ''NaN'' WHERE '|| quote_ident(cname) ||' = 999;'
```

Comment: Thank you Ilya - this has solved the schema.table referencing question. Hugely appreciated. I am now returned an error saying column 999 does not exist so now it is a different referencing issue...even though the error message quotes the query correctly:     update schema.table set column = replace(column, "999", "NaN");

Comment: have updated the original  response. I didn't noticed that you are working with non-string columns.   so the query should be like `UPDATE schema.table SET column = 'NaN' WHERE column = 999;`

Comment: EXECUTE 'update '|| (schemanm||'.'||tname)::regclass ||' set ' || quote_ident(cname) ||' = ''NaN'' where '  || quote_ident(cname) ||' = 999;'; .....I get: invalid input syntax for integer: "NaN" . how to pull together different strings/numerics/columns/tables is something I obviously have to work on!

Answer (score 2):

I would rather use `format()` for this. The placeholder `%I` takes care of properly quoting identifiers if needed.

`replace()` is for string manipulation not for replacing numbers. To assign the value NaN use `set xxx = 'NaN'` **but** you cannot do this for an `integer` value. Integers do not support `NaN`

So your dynamic SQL boils down to:

```
execute format('update %I.%I set %I = ''NaN'' where %I = 999, schemanm, tname, cname, cname);
```

But you will need to change your where clause to not include `integer` columns. You probably want to include `numeric` and `real` as well:

```
and data_type in ('numeric','double precision', 'real')
```

---

If you just want to mark the "absence of information", I would rather store `null` in those columns. In that case you don't need to distinguish between the different data types:

```
execute format('update %I.%I set %I = null where %I = 999, schemanm, tname, cname, cname);
```

Comment: Great thank you for this also. I had not realised that about integers ...so will need to change the integers to doubles (or numeric?) because we want to use 'NaN's for 'I dont know' answers from a questionnaire that occur in integers and other numeric fields. Thank you once again. Hugely appreciated

Comment: @user3770062  Why don't you use `NULL`  instead? That's the "SQL way" to store the "absence" of a value

Comment: because we need a 'not applicable' value and an 'i dont know' value. The null fields that exist in the db already are there because that particular question had not been applicable....these ones, the interviewee has responded 'i dont know;