# how to use a schema variable in a cursor declaration

Tags: postgresql

```
DO $$
    DECLARE DATABASE_TO_READ varchar DEFAULT 'db_name';
    DECLARE containers REFCURSOR;
    DECLARE dates_for_looping REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO containers EXECUTE format(' 
        SELECT
            container_id as cid,
            MIN(timestamp) AS container_start_datetime,
            MAX(timestamp) AS container_end_datetime
        FROM
            %1$s.events
        GROUP BY 
            1',DATABASE_TO_READ)
    ;
    -- ....lots of other things.....
```

The error I get is `Error : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("` on the SELECT INTO line.

I am on Postgres 9.5.01.

I understand that for right now it doesn't look like the schema name needs to be a variable, but it will have to be in order to LOOP through schemas instead of having to do a lot of UNIONs across schemas.

This question: [how to reference a schema variable in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420590/how-to-reference-a-schema-variable-in-plpgsql) would have my answer except I need to use a schema variable for a cursor declaration.

This page seems to have an answer but has a bunch of `EXEC SQL` syntax that I'm not familiar with: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ecpg-dynamic.html

Comment: It seems that you are using the `execute` command in the wrong way. [Executing Dynamic Commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for single value or use `open containers for execute format(...);` for (ref)cursors (cannot find the link to the documentation quickly).

Comment: PS: [Here is a nice tutorial about using cursors with plpgsql](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-cursor/)